# R- compare different columns of a data frame with different values

Tags: r, dplyr, while-loop, columnsorting

I am currently working on microdata, using a survey called SHARE. I want to use a variable for education but the way it was coded makes it kind of hard.

In the survey, households are asked what degree they have. There is one column for each degree and it takes the value 0 or 1 if the interviewed has the degree or not. The issue is that I have two countries with different degrees, but they are using the same column, so I have to go to the user manual to find for each country to which degree corresponds each 0 or 1. I was able to do so and then translate it to an international way of measuring education.

My idea was to sum each column and then having only one column for each household. However, I wasn't able to proceed because some people have many degrees. I would like to get the highest degree of each household. I would like to have your help on this issue.

Here are tables of what I have and what I would like:

Let imagine in Germany the first diplome is equivalent to the first diplome in international standards, the second and thee third in Germany are the same as the second diplom in international standards and the last diplom in Germany is the same as the third internationally. And in France we have first = first int., second = second int., third = third int. and no fourth diplom. Then I have a the table:

```
country= c( "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "France" , "France", "France")
degree_one= c( 1, 1, 1, 1 , 1, 1)
degree_two = c( 0, 1, 0, 1 , 1, 0)
degree_three= c( 1, 0, 1, 1 , 1, 0)
degree_four = c( 1, 0, 0, NA ,NA,  NA)

f = data.frame(country,degree_one,degree_two,degree_three,degree_four)
```

Then I can translate and try to creat my variable degree by summing everything:

```
f$degree_one = ifelse(f$country == "Germany" & f$degree_one == 1,1,f$degree_one)
f$degree_two = ifelse(f$country == "Germany" & f$degree_two == 1,2,f$degree_two)
f$degree_three = ifelse(f$country == "Germany" & f$degree_three == 1,2,f$degree_three)
f$degree_four = ifelse(f$country == "Germany" & f$degree_four == 1,3,f$degree_four)

f$degree_one = ifelse(f$country == "France" & f$degree_one == 1,1,f$degree_one)
f$degree_two = ifelse(f$country == "France" & f$degree_two == 1,2,f$degree_two)
f$degree_three = ifelse(f$country == "France" & f$degree_three == 1,3,f$degree_three)
f$degree_four = ifelse(f$country == "France" & f$degree_four == "NA",0,f$degree_four)

f = replace(f, is.na(f), 0)

f2 = f %>% mutate(degree = degree_one + degree_two + degree_three + degree_four )
```

Unfortunately, it does not work and what I would like should look like this:

```
degree = c(3,2,2,3,3,1)
f3 = data.frame(f,degree)
```

I tried to do smth with a while loop but it did not work, as anyone any idea how I can solve my problem? I tried to make it as clear as possible, I hope you will understand and that someone as an idea on how to fix this.

Thanks :)

Comment: First, in dplyr, there are few reasons to EVER use a loop to process individual items as the datastructures themselves contain all the data necessary. So...use dplyr verbs. In particular, explore group_by, select, and mutate. See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/grouping.html

Comment: As far as I know about group_by, it works with rows and not with columns, therefore it is not possible to do what I would like to do. But thanks for taking the time to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
##
#  create degree map by country
#
degreeMap <- data.table(country=c('France', 'Germany'))
degreeMap <- degreeMap[, .(degree=paste('degree', c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'), sep='_')), by=.(country)]
degreeMap[country=='France',  intlDegree:=c(1,2,3,NA)]
degreeMap[country=='Germany', intlDegree:=c(1,2,2,3)]
##
#   process your data
#
setDT(f)
f[, indx:=1:.N]                     # need an index column to recover original order
f[, HH:=1:.N, by=.(country)]        # need a  HH column to distinguish different HH w/in country
maxDegree <- melt(f, id=c('country', 'HH', 'indx'), variable.name='degree', value.name = 'flag')
maxDegree <- maxDegree[flag > 0]    # remove rows with flag=0 or NA
setorder(maxDegree, HH, degree)
maxDegree <- maxDegree[, .SD[.N], keyby=.(country, HH)]
maxDegree[degreeMap, intlDegree:=i.intlDegree, on=.(country, degree)]
setorder(maxDegree, indx)
maxDegree
##    country HH indx       degree flag intlDegree
## 1: Germany  1    1  degree_four    1          3
## 2: Germany  2    2   degree_two    1          2
## 3: Germany  3    3 degree_three    1          2
## 4:  France  1    4 degree_three    1          3
## 5:  France  2    5 degree_three    1          3
## 6:  France  3    6   degree_one    1          1
```

So this converts your `f` to a `data.table` and adds an index column and a HH column to distinguish between HH within a country.

We then convert to long format using `melt(...)`. In long format the four `degree_` columns are reduced to two columns: a `flag` column indicating whether or not the degree applies, and a `degree` column indicating which degree.

Then we remove all rows with 0 or NA flags, and then extract the last remaining row (highest degree) for each country and HH.

Finally, we join to `degreeMap` to get the equivalent intlDegree.

Comment: it seems to work, still I'm facing two issues. I cannot run the last three lines, but until "maxDegree <- maxDegree[, .SD[.N], keyby=.(country, HH)]" (include) it works and then the flag give me the highest degree. However, it eliminates I will guess NA and zero, so I lose many obs. (500) and if I dont select the flags >0 I only have flags = 0. Do you have an idea how I can fix that? Thanks it's helping me a lot! I just have to fix this issue now :)

Comment: @Jpaete This works with the MRE you provided. So your actual data set is different from the MRE? Do you have cases (rows) where all `degree_*` are 0? If that's the case update your question with an MRE that better reflects the real dataset. Or, provide a link to your actual data set (that might be better).

Comment: The dataset I provided was looking like the one I have, but I was not able to modify your code so it worked for my dataset. I found that the easier option was actually to create a new variable and then to simply use the command "pmax", then I have= degree$max = pmax(...).

Answer (score 0):

Change `NA`s to `0` and then sum degree columns:

```
f <- f %>%
    mutate(
        degree_one = ifelse(is.na(degree_one), 0, degree_one),
        degree_two = ifelse(is.na(degree_two), 0, degree_two),
        degree_three = ifelse(is.na(degree_three), 0, degree_three),
        degree_four = ifelse(is.na(degree_four), 0, degree_four),
        degree_sum = degree_one + degree_two + degree_three + degree_four
)
```

Or, if you want to get fancy with the `dplyr`

```
f <- f %>% 
    mutate(across(contains("degree"), \(x) {ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)})) %>% 
    mutate(degree_sum = select(., contains("degree")) %>% rowSums())
```

Comment: As I said, the issue is that some people have more than one degree. Therefore, I cannot just sum the columns. I need to select the highest degree obtained and if two or more degrees of the same level are obtained, I need to select only one of them. But thanks for taking the time to help me.